# Need help flipping multiple objects in a collection as a whole

Tags: modeling

[image: The objects]

Hi guys, i'm still new in blender and i'm currently trying Hard-Ops non destructive modeling, i have an issue on mirroring a collection as a whole, if i try "right click -> mirror" it will mirror based on each of the objects individual origins (which is a mess).

[image]

I also tried putting the origins to the head and ctrl+m to mirror it but it still ends up super messy

Below is an attempt to mirror the objects by 3D cursor as a pivot point

[image]

How do i mirror them as a one whole object? i've been scratching my head this whole day haha, any insight will be much appreciated :)

Comment: put the 3D cursor on the head, choose 3D cursor as Pivot Point, select the object, duplicate with shift D and enter, the S X -1?

Comment: still messing up, some objects flipped properly while some don't it's weird. This is a collection with a lot of individual objects btw, do you think making a parent for these objects will help? it'll be quite a hassle tho haha

Comment: hard to tell, maybe share one of these objects so that we can test

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something but the problem seems simple to me.

With your first described attempt you were using Individual Origins.

[image]

But I think you want to use Median Point while mirroring, and you'll get the desired result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not Join (ctrl+J) all the objects in the leg or arm together into one object. That will create one origin, and it'll be much easier to deal with. Maybe duplicate the arm first so you can get back to the individual objects easily.